# taking a symbol from edittext and save it in database

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to take a symbol from an `EditText` in my Android application and save it in the database (it's retrieved from the database and I'm editing it). For example, I have this symbol: `μ`. It will be retrived fine, but when I edit it and save the changes the symbol will be saved as a `?`, and I don't know why.

I've added this to my PHP file:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

and this is the Java code

```
class SaveglossaryDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


/**
 * Saving glossary
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    // getting updated data from EditTexts
    String Name = name.getText().toString();
    String Description = description.getText().toString();
    String Symbol = symbol.getText().toString();

    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_GID, gid));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, Name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, Description));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_SYMBOL, Symbol));

    // sending modified data through http request
    // Notice that update glossary url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_glossary,"POST", params);

    // check json success tag
    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // successfully updated
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminGlossary.class);
            i.putExtra("admin", admin);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            // failed to update glossary
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

my php code

```
<?php


// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['ID_glossary']) && isset($_POST['symbol']) && isset($_POST['name'])  && isset($_POST['description'])) {

$ID_glossary = $_POST['ID_glossary'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$symbol = $_POST['symbol'];
$description = $_POST['description'];


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// mysql update row with matched pid
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE glossary SET Symbol='$symbol', Name = '$name',     Description = '$description' WHERE ID_Glossary = $ID_glossary");
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully updated
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "glossary successfully updated.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {

}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

the db_connect

```
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

    // Selecing database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =utf8;");
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =utf8;");
    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}

/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
}

}

?>
```

How can I solve this, and where is the problem?

Comment: Can you try logging the strings to see if Java is not capturing the value correctly?

Comment: @JayS. the problem is i cant run the application on virtual machine to log it because its so large i only can run it on a real device.

Comment: Ah, well if you have the Android SDK, and enable USB debugging on the device, you can use DDMS on a computer to view the console. @lama

Comment: @JayS. i did and logged the string and the value is logged correctly! whats the problem? :(

Comment: How is it going? @lama have you figured out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I've got your problem.

Before every insert query on the server side, try adding

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```

This is because `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` tells the database what charset to expect, but the mysql is not sending it with that charset. Let me know if this works.

This may not be the problem, but if you execute `mysql_client_encoding($link);` on the php script and it does not return `utf8` then this is most likely the issue.

Also, you should know that **mysql_*** functions are deprecated. You should use **mysqli_** or **PDO**.

[Source](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4275612.htm)

Comment: tried it but didn't work too .. how can i use mysql_client_encoding($link); in my code ? i just copy and paste it as it is ?because i did and nothing returned

Comment: i posted my full php file

Comment: can you also post the `db_connect` class? Because the link should be inside that. And if we know that, we can also fix the `mysql_set_charset` as well. I've edited my answer. @lama

Comment: i posted it, it was set to latin1 then i changed them to utf8 and it didnt solve the problem :(

Comment: how did you "change it"? @lama

Answer (score 0):

Ok now that I've seen more code, I see you're doing alot of things wrong.

Here's a [pastie](http://pastie.org/private/mnnwng4x9jpxhmd8tnwhw) you can use to see the changes I've made.

Comment: Oh my. I dunno. Perhaps try and delete the question and repost? Maybe someone else could help you.. @lama

Comment: ok i will.. really THANK YOU SO MUCH for the effort and for not ignoring me !!

Comment: Yeah no problem @lama